# I have some problem using the SQL like operator

Tags: sql, node.js

In the API we just write `('xyz/: title'),(req, res)` and in the body when I define the API by SQL query like `{ select * from users where username = ?, [req, params, xyz] }`
then it's working properly but I want to use SQL 'like' operator and it's not working proply as shown
{ " app.get('/search/:title', (req, res) => {

```
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT users.id, users.name, search.id, search.title, search.userid FROM users inner join search on users.id = search.id  where title like = ?', [req.params.title], (err, row, fields) =>{
       if(!err) 
       res.send(row);
       else
       console.log(err);
    })
}); " }
```

please can anyone explain this

Comment: ``` like = ? ```` please remove `=`

Comment: but if i remove then how i find my result which is starting from any world like a, bf, fd, ei, etc

Comment: A correct SQL statement would use something like `somefield LIKE 'somevalue%'`, no `=` there

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a query like

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, search.id, search.title, search.userid FROM users inner join search on users.id = search.id  where title like ?'
```

and make sure that if by `like` you mean contains, then put a `%` at the start and at the end of the parameter value.

Comment: how to use %  at start and end can you explain please

Comment: @NaeemShahzad see if this works: `...  where title like '%' + ? + '%' ` - depending on the database you may need `&` or `|` instead of `+`

Comment: @NaeemShahzad I would try `['%' + req.params.title + '%']`.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing that might work. I do not have the means to test it right now, but is' a perfectly rational suggestion.